# How to sort one array based on another, when elements repeat, in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, comparator

I have two ArrayLists

A: 5 3 2 6 1 4

B: 0 1 2 0 3 2

I want to sort B, based on corresponding values from A, so I should get : 3 2 1 2 0 0

When I use the following codes :

```
ArrayList<Integer> D=new ArrayList<Integer>(B);
Collections.sort(B, Comparator.comparing(s -> A.get(D.indexOf(s))));
```

or :

```
   ArrayList<Integer> D = new ArrayList<Integer>(B);
   Collections.sort(B, new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare(Integer a,Integer b){
            return Integer.compare(A.get(D.indexOf(a)),A.get(D.indexOf(b)));
        }
   });
```

It would have worked if the elements in B were unique, but since both 2 and 0 has 2 occurances, every time `A.get(D.indexOf(2))` is called, 2 is returned and 4 is never returned.

So I finally get : 3 2 2 1 0 0

Can anyone help me with a comparator that deals with this? I don't want to make a full sorting algorithm, but such solutions are also welcome.

Comment: This is impossible to do with a comparator, simply because what you are trying to do here, is not sorting.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = List.of(5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 4);
        List<Integer> list2 = List.of(0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2);
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer i : list1) {
            tempList.add(list2.get(i - 1));
        }
        System.out.println(tempList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

**[Update]**

Given below is an updated solution to meet OP's new requirement mentioned in the comment below the answer.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> list1 = List.of(15, 13, 12, 16, 11, 14);
        List<Integer> list2 = List.of(0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2);
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        int max = Collections.max(list1);
        int offset = max - list2.size() + 1;
        for (Integer i : list1) {
            tempList.add(list2.get(i - offset));
        }
        System.out.println(tempList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I think this looks like an answer specific to only this question, but I wanted an answer that suits a wide range of test cases. List A could be: 15,13,12,16,11,14; in which case we will not get this answer.

Comment: @somuchsonal - I've posted an update to meet this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.